# when i run electron . in electron-quick0start.It's error with cli.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

see,i install electron is success,but i run electron . or electron -v.It's error and
It's run in windows10.

```
  C:\Windows\System32\electron-quick-start>electron -v
   module.js:457
      throw err;
      ^

   Error: Cannot find module               'C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\electron-prebuilt\cli.js'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:455:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:403:25)
     at Module.runMain (module.js:590:10)
     at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:149:9)
     at bootstrap_node.js:509:3
```

i try to use :

```
 npm i -g nrm`
```

to fix this:

```
  C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\nrm ->        C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\nrm\cli.js
```

it's install electron success,but run also is bad.

```
  |   `-- es6-promise@3.3.1
  `-- extract-zip@1.5.0
    +-- concat-stream@1.5.0
    | +-- inherits@2.0.3
    | +-- readable-stream@2.0.6
    | | +-- core-util-is@1.0.2
    | | +-- isarray@1.0.0
    | | +-- process-nextick-args@1.0.7
    | | +-- string_decoder@0.10.31
    | | `-- util-deprecate@1.0.2
    | `-- typedarray@0.0.6
    +-- debug@0.7.4
    +-- mkdirp@0.5.0
    | `-- minimist@0.0.8
    `-- yauzl@2.4.1
      `-- fd-slicer@1.0.1
        `-- pend@1.2.0
```

and this my path:

```
  C:\Windows\System32\electron-quick-start>npm root -g
  C:\Users\MyUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules

 C:\Windows\System32\electron-quick-start>node
  > global.module.paths
 [ 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\electron-quick-start\\repl\\node_modules',
   'C:\\Windows\\System32\\electron-quick-start\\node_modules',
   'C:\\Windows\\System32\\node_modules',
   'C:\\Windows\\node_modules',
   'C:\\node_modules',
   'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.node_modules',
   'C:\\Users\\MyUserName\\.node_libraries',
   'H:\\lib\\node' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Now,I fix it.It's path worry!
I do this:

```
cd 'C:\\Windows\\System32\\electron-quick-start
 npm i electron-prebuilt
```

and it's run ok!